# Does adding [NotMapped] to a partial class avoid mapping the entire class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have set up my EF code-first database but want to add additional derived properties.  (Yes, it should be in a view model, we can discuss another time why it is this way.)  I have created a partial class extending the actual table class.  If I add a `[NotMapped]` to the new partial, will it avoid mapping the additional properties I add there or will it apply to the entire class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will apply to the entire class. Remember that a partial class is simply a way of splitting a class into multiple files. From the [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/wa80x488.aspx):

> At compile time, attributes of partial-type definitions are merged.

So this:

```
[SomeAttribute]
partial class PartialEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

[AnotherAttribute]
partial class PartialEntity 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is equivalent to writing:

```
[SomeAttribute]
[AnotherAttribute]
partial class PartialEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to add a partial class without having the properties included in the model, you will need to add the `NotMapped` attribute to the individual items:

```
partial class PartialEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

partial class PartialEntity 
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```